# Why can't i relate notes to sound?

Tags: ear-training

So when I started searching for music theory I started practicing solfege, using a DAW based on sheet music and tried to learn interval recognition.
But for some reason I can't relate this things to actual sounds like how you can read a book or poem without trying to speak it.
From the solfege and interval recognition I learnt the throat positions/movements of most notes and intervals; from the DAW I learnt to see the sheet and have an basic idea of the harmonic content.
But when I sight read everything that goes to my mind is either "C G D E" or these throat positions. Also when I hear something I can't relate back to notes. What is the problem? Where did I done something wrong?

Comment: Hi! Hearing the notes while looking at music is called audiation, so this pre-existing question might be a duplicate: [How do you practice Audiation (playing music in your head)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11653/how-do-you-practice-audiation-playing-music-in-your-head) Try also browsing other questions that are under the "ear-training" tag. (But the simplest answer is: it takes time! You probably couldn't read written language for the first 5 or more years of your life. These skills can be grown over time.

Comment: @AndyBonner probably is it. i've been only months in it. THANKS!